# SQL loops in PHP to JSON with 2 tables based on the id of the related table

Tags: php, json

I hope you are always healthy.
I am having trouble generating an array (json) of 2 tables.
the table that I have is as follows.
app_produk_ready this
[tabel 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVO4a.png)

app_produk_ready_img this
[tabel 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvkwR.png)

php code that I made

```
<?php
require_once('connection.php');
$response = array();
      $query = mysqli_query($CON,"SELECT * FROM app_produk_ready");
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
            $id=(int)$row['id'];
            $kain=$row['kain'];
            $seri=$row['seri'];
            $harga=(int)$row['harga'];
            $stok=$row['stok'];   
            $data['id']=$id;
            $data['kain']=$kain;
            $data['seri']=$seri;
            $data['harga']=$harga;
            $data['stok']=$stok;
            $tableImage=mysqli_query($CON,"SELECT image FROM app_produk_ready_img WHERE id=$id");
            while($img = mysqli_fetch_array($tableImage)){
            $gambar=$img['image'];
            $data['images'][]=$gambar;
      }
      $response[] = $data; 
}
echo json_encode($response);
mysqli_close($CON);
?>
```

But the results I get on the image actually accumulate on the loop. examples of wrong results

```
[
{
id: 1,
kain: "Katun Jepang",
seri: "SR01",
harga: 55000,
stok: "100",
images: [
"https://sweetroommedan.com/app2/img_ready/1-1.jpg",
"https://sweetroommedan.com/app2/img_ready/1-2.jpg",
"https://sweetroommedan.com/app2/img_ready/1-3.jpg"
]
},
{
id: 2,
kain: "Katun Jepang",
seri: "SR02",
harga: 55000,
stok: "100",
images: [
"https://sweetroommedan.com/app2/img_ready/1-1.jpg",
"https://sweetroommedan.com/app2/img_ready/1-2.jpg",
"https://sweetroommedan.com/app2/img_ready/1-3.jpg",
"https://sweetroommedan.com/app2/img_ready/2-1.jpg",
"https://sweetroommedan.com/app2/img_ready/2-2.jpg"
]
},
]
```

What i want should be

```
[
{
id: 1,
kain: "Katun Jepang",
seri: "SR01",
harga: 55000,
stok: "100",
images: [
"https://sweetroommedan.com/app2/img_ready/1-1.jpg",
"https://sweetroommedan.com/app2/img_ready/1-2.jpg",
"https://sweetroommedan.com/app2/img_ready/1-3.jpg"
]
},
{
id: 2,
kain: "Katun Jepang",
seri: "SR02",
harga: 55000,
stok: "100",
images: [
"https://sweetroommedan.com/app2/img_ready/2-1.jpg",
"https://sweetroommedan.com/app2/img_ready/2-2.jpg"
]
},
{
id: 3,
kain: "Katun Jepang",
seri: "SR03",
harga: 55000,
stok: "100",
images: [
"https://sweetroommedan.com/app2/img_ready/3-1.jpg",
"https://sweetroommedan.com/app2/img_ready/3-2.jpg",
"https://sweetroommedan.com/app2/img_ready/3-3.jpg",
"https://sweetroommedan.com/app2/img_ready/3-4.jpg"
]
}
]
```

What do I need to do to get the results I expect? thanks for the help.

Comment: `$data['images'] = [];` before the inner `while` loop?

Comment: Yeah, i want to looping image on tabel 2 in tabel 1 by id. Any method with 1 query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to reset the data array for each new row from the outer query.

i.e.

```
$response = array();
  $query = mysqli_query($CON,"SELECT * FROM app_produk_ready");
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
     data=array();
     (...)
```

Your problem is that you are adding data onto the data['images'] array without ever resetting it.

Comment: I know that I'm too late, just to thank you. I just got my account back, thank you very much, perfect answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use two query's individualy? You can use inner join

```
 SELECT * 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2
      ON table1.primaryKey=table2.table1Id
```

See: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp for more details

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but previously I have used a single query, but it doesn't work as desired, because the image in table 2 has a lot of data.